# Android Wear OS Complication Provider Types - Multiple Options

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-complication

Anyone know how to create a layered complication provider menu with multiple types? For example, Google Fit now has a layered menu... you can click on the Google Fit complication provider and you get 3 options, and when you click on an option, there is another menu with more options...

Basically I'd like to have a menu like this:

```
Battery: 
            - Long
            - Short
            - Small Image
Date: 
            - Long
            - Short
            - Small Image
```

Etc...

Comment: I don't see a Fit complication that lets you choose type like this, I'm only seeing ones that let you choose something the app has control over. Can you point me to one that works like this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve something like the Date example above you would have to create three different providers in your app. They would all serve the same data, but each one would only support one specific complication data type.

I don't recommend doing this since the watch face is supposed to be in charge of prioritizing what data types it's best suited to display.